# Once I pass an array through Node.js as an object how do I control the data in my ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm creating a basic calendar app with Node.js and ejs.I'm trying to pass an array of months through express to my ejs and I want to be able to go through each month when I press the next button. How do I add that functionality.

Here is the code in Node.js.

```
const Months = [
"January",
"February",
"March",
"April",
"May",
"June",
"July",
"August",
"September",
"October",
"November",
"December"
];
```

As you can see I'm passing the Months as an object through my main route.

```
// main route
app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.render("main", {Months: Months});
});
```

This is part of my ejs file

```
<div class="container">
 <ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none">
<li class="prev" style="float: left; padding-top: 10px; color: white; font-size: 20px; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px;">

<!-- this is the previous button, when pressed should go back one month -->
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Previous</button></li>

<li class="next" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 10px; color: white; font-size: 20px; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px;">

<!-- This is the next button, when pressed should go on the next month  -->
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Next</button></li>

<li style="color: white; font-size: 20px; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px; text-align: center;">
```

This is where I'm passing the Month object. How do I control the data here so when I press the Next or Previous button I can loop through the data.

```
<%= Months[0] %><br>
  <span style="font-size:18px">2016</span>
</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the `months` array in client-side Javascript?  If so, you need to actually render that array as Javascript inside a `<script>` tag in the path.  Though, since the array is not dynamic, you could just write it directly into a script tag in your page.  You don't need to pass something that never changes into the renderer.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try to do that, thanks.  @jfriend00

Answer (score 0):

The value is only available on the server side. If you decode the value, you can use it on the clientside.

Here is a simple example.

```
<p id="month"></p>
<p>
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
</p>
<script>
let months = <%- JSON.stringify(Months) %>;

let index = 0;

let el = document.getElementById('month');

document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', e => {
index--;

index = index < 0 ? 0 : index;

el.innerHTML = months[index];
});

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', e => {
index++;

index = index >= months.length ? months.length - 1 : index;

el.innerHTML = months[index];
});
</script>
```

Comment: ok, I didn't know I could manipulate the data using jquery in ejs. Thank You so much. By the way, if I want to make the jquery an external file do I have to put it in public folder or where should I put so my code is clean.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jquery. Something as small as this could just go into your view file. You shouldn't create a new file for a view specific code segment. NodeJS is serversided, thus the variables are only present at render time on the clientside, after that you can't access any serversided variables without the use of a http request on the clientside.